# Taking multiple images using Camera2

Tags: android, preview, photo-gallery, android-camera2

I followed this coding tutorial [ANDROID CAMERA2 API EXAMPLE TUTORIAL](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/) to capture a single image through Camera2.
However, I cannot find any thing on how to take several images by Camera2.
Beside, I want to preview the taken photo, there are enormous examples for preview through intend, but I cannot find that how to preview the taken image without using the intend?
Do you know any good tutorial or good guide in these regards.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I mean, do you want to capture N frames after you click in a button? what have you tried? In few words you will change the way to get the imageReader callback and  you can display your photos in java imageViews converting the imagereader image in a bitmap.